# All error messages printing if ONE of the inputs is wrong on form - React Form

Tags: reactjs, forms, error-handling, jsx

I am currently showing error messages on submit through checking if the response.status has failed, but i am not sure how to map for each error and am currently printing all error messages even if only one input is wrong. I always want to display a green "Your message has been sent!" Text in a basic

tag when everything is correct and submitted.

I have attempted mapping the error fields but im not sure how to do it correctly. I am trying to use error.field === 'fullName' which i thought would work.

```
class Contactus extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      form: {
        fullName: null,
        email: null,
        subject: null,
        message: null,
      },
      formErrors: {
        name: "",
        email: "",
        subject: "",
        message: "",
      }
    }
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
  }
  onSubmit() {

    const { form } = this.state

    Http.post('/contact-form', { data: form }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)

      if (response.status === 'failed') {
        this.setState({ formErrors: { name: 'error message' } })

        const errors = response.data.errors
        errors.map((error, key) => {
          error.field === 'fullName'
        }
        )
      }

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

....

```
render() {
    const props = this.props
    const { form } = this.state
    const { formErrors } = this.state
    return (
      <React.Fragment>

        <div id="contact-us" className="container">
          <div className="row background-image">
            <div className="form col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
              <form onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); this.onSubmit(); }}>
                <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                <p>Use the contact below to get in touch with the team at the Front. We’d love to hear from you!<br />
                  <br />
                  <strong>Please note: We don’t take bookings via this website or a phone call.</strong></p>
                <span>
                  {formErrors.name !== '' && <p>Please enter Name</p>}
                </span>
                <label>
                  Full Name:
                  <input type="text" className="" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ form: { ...form, fullName: e.target.value } }) }} />
                </label>
                <p></p>
                <span>
                  {formErrors.email !== '' && <p>Please enter valid email address</p>}
                </span>
```

.....

Currently im printing all error messages above in the input on the form in a red styled

.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, I found 2 problems.

1. You are just replacing the whole `formErrors` object in the state, i.e the existing values are lost after using this: `this.setState({ formErrors: { name: 'error message' } })` Instead you should be using `this.setState({formErrors: { ...this.state.formErrors, name: 'error message' } })`
2. After the execution of this line in your code `this.setState({ formErrors: { name: 'error message' } })` the email becomes `undefined` and not `<blank>` and you are checking the condition for blank in this: `{formErrors.email !== '' && <p>Please enter valid email address</p>}` and similarly for name. Instead you should be using `{!!formErrors.email && <p>Please enter valid email address</p>}`

Once you fix above, your code will just run fine.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I made the changes but now the error messages are visible on loading the page and do not go away when i enter correctly

Comment: I just updated my answer, i missed an `!` So if you have any value in `formErrors.email` or `formErrors.name` then error message will appear
`{!!formErrors.email && <p>Please enter valid email address</p>}`

Comment: It works for name, but not for the other inputs. What do i add to this.setState({formErrors: { ...this.state.formErrors, name: 'error message' } }) , section to grab the other error inputs. Also, even though it does work, one entering one input, the error message stays. 
Thank you :)

Comment: Didn't get you there, what do you mean by it only works for `name`? and you need to add a validation method which checks the field validity and based on that updates the value in the state. And call it onBlur.

Comment: It gives me an error message even when i have entered a name.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved this by leaving my code as is except delete the

```
// const errors = response.data.errors
// errors.map((error, key) => {
//   error.field === ''
// }
// )
```

and add:

```
if (response.status === 'failed' && response.data.errors[0].field === "fullName") {
        this.setState({ formErrors: { ...this.state.formErrors, name: 'error message' } })
        return

      } else if (response.status === 'failed' && response.data.errors[0].field === "email") {
        this.setState({ formErrors: { ...this.state.formErrors, email: 'error message' } })
        return
```